# How to recieve emails with SES and post to sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am trying to forward all incoming emails to a SNS topic, in order to process them using a Lambda function. When I send an email to the designated address it triggers the lambda function, which fails. The reason for the failure is that instead of the email body I sent being in the SNS topic, I get this:

*You received this message because you attempted to set up Amazon SES to deliver emails to this SNS topic.*

*Please note that the rule that you configured to deliver emails to this SNS topic is only valid if the entire setup process is successful. For more information about setting up email-receiving rules, see the Amazon SES Developer Guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html*

It is clearly being triggered by an email arriving so its not a DNS issue. Looking through the documentation this should  be only an issue if the SES and Topic are linked to different AWS accounts, which are they are not.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> You received this message because you attempted to set up Amazon SES to deliver emails to this SNS topic.

This message is normal.  It is sent when you create a rule that references an SNS topic.  SES appears to do this in order to avoid allowing you to create a rule pointing to a topic that isn't going to work.

I just created a rule referencing a topic and received exactly this message.  Note this, from the SNS message:

```
"source":"no-reply-aws@amazon.com",
"messageId":"AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION",
"destination":["recipient@example.com"]
```

**I didn't edit any of those fields.**  This is exactly how they arrived (even recipient@example.com).

If you see this as well, this is almost certainly not being triggered by the arrival of an actual email, but actually being triggered by configuring the topic in a rule.

Comment: Okay, so how do you go about making sure that it is triggered by the actual arrival of the email then?